# How to: Update SQL Azure DB, Code First Migrations, TFS Deployment

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

Is there a way to update a SQL Azure database using Code First Migrations when a website is deployed from Team Foundation Service (TFS in the cloud)?

I was able to add a new table locally using code and the following commands:

PM> add-migration ...

PM> update-database

I don't see any way to execute these command when I check in my code and TFS deploys the website to Azure.

Membership Provider tables *are* getting created, but not my new table "ExternalUserInformation".

Comment: No, I didn't. Sorry. :-(

Answer (score 2):

I've spend the last 3 days looking the way to do this. I found this page: 
http://architects.dzone.com/articles/continuous-deployment-windows-0

but until now I could not make the WebDeploy to execute the code-first migrations.

if you find the solution, please post here.

Best regards
Paulo Aboim Pinto
Zurich - Suiça